# Django - ajax call conditional method

Tags: ajax, django

i want to remove a record by ajax call, when if condition is true. but my ajax alway remove it. how to solve it?

```
def delete_order(request, pk, user=None):
    try:
        if request.user == 'owner':
            order = Food.objects.get(food_name=order.order_name).price
            latestCredit = Credit.objects.filter(user = request.user).last().creditAmount
            nextCredit = float(latestCredit) + float(orderPrice)
            q = Credit(user = request.user, creditAmount = nextCredit, status='1')
            q.save()
            order.delete()
            return HttpResponse("removed")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("you cant removed")

    except Exception:

        return HttpResponse("error occured")
```

ajax

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    url_delete = 'my-url.com;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url_delete,
        data:$(".delete_reserv").serialize(),
        success:function(data) {

            $row.remove();

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check for the response text in the ajax call:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    url_delete = 'my-url.com;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url_delete,
        data:$(".delete_reserv").serialize(),
        success:function(data) {
            if(data == 'removed') {
                $row.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```